# "brew formula" installation logs

Tags: install, homebrew

Sometimes I install a formula with Brew, and I get a series of warnings and notifications.   At some point later, I want to go back and read what problems the installation found.

Does brew automatically keep track of these installation logs?  If not, is there any way I could instruct it (perhaps with a parameter) to always record the installation log on a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logs are stored in **~/Library/Logs/Homebrew**.
You can browse this in Finder or using Console.app.

---

If you want to save your own log of an install, you can use…

> ```
> brew install <formula> 2>&1 | tee install.log
> ```

<sup>Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/10430</sup>